# Interactive charts presentation in Google Slides

Tags: javascript, d3.js, google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I'm looking for a way to have interactive charts built with `D3.js` or `DC.js` in Google Slides. Is there a way to develop interactive charts into a slide and having interactive support when doing a presentation?

Farther question: Is it possible to stream data and update the presentations chart automatically?

Comment: google-sites could help to make unconventional slides with interactive charts. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70229830/3521099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible.

If a presentation tool supports embedding an iFrame, you can develop interactive charts in [observable](https://observablehq.com) and [export them as an iFrame](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/introduction-to-embedding). Embedded charts are interactive and update if the data source change (even in real time, if you code this functionality on the chart). Note that using an iFrame requires internet connection to fetch the chart from the observable servers.

Unfortunately [Google Slides do not support iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441983/embed-an-iframe-tweet-into-google-slides).